# Does the Markov property still hold for time-reverse of a Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

For a discrete-state Markov chain, the probability of next state is independent of previous states given current state:

$
P(X_{t+1}|X_t,X_{t-1},...,X_1)=P(X_{t+1}|X_t)
$

I hope to know whether Markov property still holds for the time-reversal of the above formula. Is the probability of previous state independent of the future states given present state?

$
P(X_{t-1}|X_t,X_{t+1},...,X_T) \stackrel{?}{=} P(X_{t-1}|X_t)
$

Comment: Yes assuming you start with a stationary distribution.  Markov property says "the future is independent of the past given present" so can be restated as "the past is independent of the future given present".